# Will placing the <script> tags after </body>, but before </html>, speed up the page performance?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, pagespeed

I have read a StackOverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53585251/1661640), as it says:

> Also, place the `<script>` tags at the bottom of the page, even after
> `</body>`, but before `</html>`. This will load the scripts last and load
> the ads last.

Is it real? Why it would work?

Comment: It works because the HTML is loaded first and able to be displayed by the browser before the JavaScript is loaded or processed.

Comment: "even after </body>", don't do that, the parser will have to move it back in the body, through an error handling, and your doc won't pass validators anymore. + instead of doing what this answer says, better use the  `async` attribute on your script (or `defer` if you need it to be called before DOMContentLoaded).

Answer (score 1):

Loading a "classic" script is synchronous by default. This means that when the script tag is encountered, the HTML parser will wait for this script to be downloaded and executed before it is able to continue parsing what follows.

So, yes, putting your script at the end of the markup will allow the parser to have gathered enough DOM information and stylesheets and everything before it gets blocked fetching that script.
The renderer may even be able to pre-render the page while this script is being fetched, making it looks like the page did load faster.

But no, placing it after the  tag won't make anything "speed up" in comparison to placing it before. This will just create an error in the parser, which will have to move it back inside the <body>, and it will make your page fail to pass validators. (Though to be fair, this was not the claim made in that quote).

Also, note that just doing this that way will still block the parser synchronously, and thus, all the asynchronous tasks that should happen at the end of the parsing will still get delayed.

So the best if you want to load a script that doesn't need to execute synchronously is to load it with the [`async` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of adding  at bottom of the page is, controlling the compile-time errors.

Consider the scenario, we have written some addClass() functionality to an ID element, if we include this in top it can't find out the Id element.

So we are adding it to the bottom of the page, once the DOM has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

*TL:DR; faster? No, not really. The impression of loading faster? Yes.*

When the browser is rendering the DOM and it comes across a `<script>` tag, it must halt, execute the JavaScript, then continue. This is because the JS could be doing anything, like appending another element, where the order is necessary. If it queued the script for loading later or made it async, by the time the script finished executing the state of the DOM might not have been the same when the script first started loading.

E.g, consider the following:

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<script>document.body.innerHTML+="Wor"</script>
<p>ld!</p>
```

In this case, the order of the tags is necessary. If the browser queued the script to be loaded later, the last paragraph tag may have been rendered before the script inserted `Wor` into the body innerHTML, and you would end up with:

```
Hello
ld!
Wor`
```

But what if your script is doing some intense work that could lag out the browser for a few seconds? If you put the script tag in the middle of the body, half the page would be rendered, the script would be run, then the other half would be rendered (after script execution finishes). This gives the impression that the first half loads immediately, but the second half took a few seconds to load.

This causes a bad user experience. Instead, what's recommended is to move the script tag to the bottom, so only once the browser has finished rendering the elements should the script be run. This isn't *faster*, it just gives the *impression* of being faster.

Comment: Execution of scripts will block *most* renderers (all I've seen). Some may prerender during the fetching though.